# Open dialog with JavaScript button

Tags: javascript

I found the following code which shows the "open file dialog".

```
var fileSelector = document.createElement('input');

fileSelector.setAttribute('type', 'file');

var selectDialogueLink = document.createElement('a');

selectDialogueLink.setAttribute('href', '');
selectDialogueLink.innerText = "Select File";
selectDialogueLink.onclick = function () {
    fileSelector.click();
    return false;
}

document.body.appendChild(selectDialogueLink);
```

How can I have this function on an existing button called PSD["Buttonname"]? And how do I get the name of the selected file in a string? I would love to have this in plain JavaScript.

Could anybody please push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

innerText is something you used to use in the dark ages of the browser wars. These days you use textContent = "text"; For adding an event to any DOM node you use

```
fileSelector.addEventListener( "click", function(){ alert( "here be dragons" ); });
```

Maybe your button has an id so you could use

```
document.getElementById( "someID" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){ alert( "here be dragons" ); });
```

Comment: that makes sense. i managed to get the functionn on my button. i am still confused, where i find the name of the selected file.

Comment: found it: its in fileSelector.value.